# Try to MatchAll a string in Power Apps

Tags: match, preg-match-all, powerapps

I've been programming in Power Apps for some time now (but I'm not a specialist). I'm trying to pass an array from Power Automate to Power Apps.

I was able to do that with a string and after a few more steps I have the following text:

[{"Messung":1;"Tiegel leer":"16;5469";"Tiegel Probe":"27;6659";"Tiegel Asche":"17;6549"}]";"[{"Messung":2;"Tiegel leer":"16;9654";"Tiegel Probe":"26;5476";"Tiegel Asche":"17;6549"}]";"[{"Messung":3;"Tiegel leer":"17;0256";"Tiegel Probe":"27;9862";"Tiegel Asche":"18;2235"}"]

I would like to convert this back to a data table with a MatchAll command, unfortunately I do not understand the Microsoft explanation for this command at all. I can convert the semicolons in the values ​​back into commas later, but I needed the semicolons (language dependency, programming in German)

My plan was to do the conversion using a ClearCollect(MatchAll....) command.
I seem to be able to get these individually for my individual columns
(; <Tiegel_leer>;<Tiegel_Probe> & <Tiegel_Asche>).

ClearCollect(ResultAG;MatchAll(Label40_1.Text;"(""Messung"":(?[^""]*))"));;
ClearCollect(ResultAG;MatchAll(Label40_1.Text;"(""Tiegel Probe"":(?<Tiegel_Probe>[^""]*))"));;
ClearCollect(ResultAG;MatchAll(Label40_1.Text;"(""Tiegel leer"":(?<Tiegel_leer>[^""]*))"));;
ClearCollect(ResultAG;MatchAll(Label40_1.Text;"(""Tiegel Asche"":(?<Tiegel_Asche>[^""]*))"))

But I can't connect these lines with each other and I still don't really understand it. These lines were also created more by trial and error than by understanding.

Would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Using MatchAll approach is very old and complex approach to parse the array of objects (data) sent from Power automate to Power apps.

I would suggest you to use the recently released **ParseJSON** function in Power apps  instead of MatchAll function for this.

For detailed information and tutorial, check:

1. [Power Fx: Introducing ParseJSON](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-fx-introducing-parsejson/)
2. [ParseJSON function in Power Apps (experimental)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-parsejson)
3. [ParseJSON function in Power Apps - Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqfLiJDdC3Q)

Comment: and the Jason can convert a string into an array?

Comment: The ParseJSON function will parse a valid JSON string and return an untyped object representing the JSON structure.